# SQL query for the given relation

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

there are 3 tables "user", "blog" and "images"
a single user can have multiple blogs

a single blog can have multiple images and visa verse
that is multiple images can be used for multiple blogs

I need a query for total number of images in a single blog..

And I also need a query for total number of images per user..

please guide with query to fetch data..

my database created is like this:

Create table Author ( Id int , Name nvarchar(max) );

Create table Image ( Id int ,ImagePath nvarchar(max) );

Create table Blog ( Id int ,Name nvarchar(max) ,AuthorId int );

Create table BlogImages ( Id int ,BlogId int ,ImageId int );

ALTER TABLE Blog ADD FOREIGN KEY (AuthorId) REFERENCES Author(Id)

ALTER TABLE BlogImages ADD FOREIGN KEY (BlogId) REFERENCES Blog(Id)

ALTER TABLE BlogImages ADD FOREIGN KEY (ImageId) REFERENCES Image(Id)

In above relation I have a table BlogImages having blogId and ImageId , which means single imageID can have multiple blogIds , so multiple blogs using the same image

Comment: ca you provide an example on www.sqlfiddle.com of your tables?

Comment: pls provide some sample data

Comment: sir  i have provided my tables ..so that now u can guide me properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Reply to modified question:*

For number of images in a single blog:

```
select COUNT(Image.Id)
from Image, BlogImages
where Image.Id = BlogImages.ImageId
and BlogImages.BlogId = @BlogId
```

where `@BlogId` is the id of the blog you want to count images for.

For number of images by user:

```
select COUNT(Image.Id)
from Image, BlogImages, Blog
where Image.Id = BlogImages.ImageId
and BlogImages.BlogId = Blog.Id
and Blog.AuthorId = @AuthorId
```

where `@AuthorId` is the id of the user you want to count images for.

You should add `distinct` after the `select` keyword if you do not want to count the same image twice.

Comment: sir  i have provided my tables ..so that now u can guide me properly

Comment: @user2631770 I updated my answer to fit your modified question.

Comment: Why not use a proper join?

Comment: @Sam Behind the scenes the `where` syntax is an inner join and in my opinion it is easier to read for a human. As long as I just need inner joins and nothing else, I always use `where`.

Comment: I know it doesn't matter behind the scenes (yay for good compilers). I personally find it easier to understand if it says `JOIN X ON Y.ID = X.ID` though. Especially in larger queries it makes it immediately clear that you are doing an inner join. Preference I suppose :)

Comment: Yes that's true. But queries which only use inner joins usually do not get as large. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For getting total number of images per user try following query

```
select U.userId,count(*) from
(
select U.userId,I.imageId from user U,blog B, images I
where B.userId==U.userId and B.blogId==I.blogId
)
group by U.userId
```

And for  total number of images in a single blog use following

```
select B.blogId,count(*) from
(
select B.blogId,I.imageId from blog B,images I
where B.blogId==I.blogId
)
group by B.blogId
```

Comment: sir  i have provided my tables ..so that now u can guide me properly